# Litecoin query re Wemineltc

Tags: wallet, litecoin

Wondering if you can help me out with question..

I was mining litecoin with WemineLTC some years ago...  I am aware that they have now disappeared from the market.. I have or had 10 coins which were transferred into my wallet on my PC and have sat there for the last few years doing nothing..  Have these been lost or can they still be redeemed.

Thank you in anticipation

Answer (score -1):

Find the seed phrase you used for your wallet, or open your wallet and transfer them to an exchange.

The actual coins are still on your computer - they are just some strings.
So you need to open your local wallet or restore it using the seed phrase.
Sell the LTC to convert to something else. LTC just isn't worth it.